# How to set the separator for HttpHeaders?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

In my WebApi application is there anyway to get the raw data when multiple headers have the same name?

When passing in multiple Http headers with the same name they get joined with a ', ' as a separator. The `HttpHeaders` class under `System.Net.Http.Headers` seems to be the culprit.

Some of my headers contain commas so using a comma as the separator is not ideal.

I'd like to either change the separator to be something a little less common (of my choice) or be able to access the values before they are joined.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double checking the spec, it looks like comma is a reserved character used to specify multiple header field-values under the same field-name: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be
>   present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that
>   header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)].
>   It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one
>   "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the
>   message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each
>   separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same
>   field-name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation
>   of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT change the
>   order of these field values when a message is forwarded.”